# apache giving 403 forbidden for downloading .py files

Tags: python, apache, http-status-code-403

I have a mac mini running a web server (OS X 10.9.3 Server), which runs apache.

I have several python (.py) files I want my users to be able to view in a web browser.

When they navigate to the file, instead of downloading it they get a `403` forbidden message.

`/var/log/apache2/error` shows:

`[Sat Jun 21 10:33:40 2014] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/xxx/file.py`

but I don't want the python file to be executed, just to be served up --- either downloaded or shown in plain text in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add file `.htaccess` with

```
RemoveHandler .py
```

in folder with your `.py` files